# Java stream поиск по возрасту во вложенных списках

Tags: java, java-stream

Как в одну строчку написать stream, который найдет из списка страны в котором есть список людей, людей возраст которых больше 28 лет

Вот так не работает

```
List<People> listPeople1 = countryList.stream().forEach(p -> p.getPeopleList().stream().filter(q -> q.getAge() > 28).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Класс Country

```
import java.util.List;

public class Country {

private List<People> peopleList;
private String nameCountry;

public Country(String nameCountry) {
    this.nameCountry = nameCountry;
}

public List<People> getPeopleList() {
    return peopleList;
}

public void setPeopleList(List<People> peopleList) {
    this.peopleList = peopleList;
}

public String getNameCountry() {
    return nameCountry;
}

public void setNameCountry(String nameCountry) {
    this.nameCountry = nameCountry;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Country{" +
            "peopleList=" + peopleList +
            ", nameCountry='" + nameCountry + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Класс People

```
public class People {

private String name;
private int age;

public People(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "People{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            '}';
}
}
```

Класс Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
    Country country1 = new Country("USA");
    List<People> peopleList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    peopleList1.add(new People("Kevin", 27));
    peopleList1.add(new People("Arnold", 28));
    peopleList1.add(new People("Serg", 35));
    country1.setPeopleList(peopleList1);
    Country country2 = new Country("Russia");
    List<People> peopleList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    peopleList2.add(new People("Aleksey", 40));
    peopleList2.add(new People("Fedor", 37));
    peopleList2.add(new People("Ivan", 25));
    country2.setPeopleList(peopleList2);
    Country country3 = new Country("Germany");
    List<People> peopleList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    peopleList3.add(new People("Vander", 38));
    peopleList3.add(new People("Arkin", 18));
    peopleList3.add(new People("Philip", 25));
    country3.setPeopleList(peopleList3);
    countryList.add(country1);
    countryList.add(country2);
    countryList.add(country3);

    List<People> listPeople1 = countryList.stream().forEach(p -> p.getPeopleList().stream().filter(q -> q.getAge() > 28).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
}
```

Comment: Если вам дали ответ, который решает вашу проблему, то плюсаните и примите его, нажав на стрелку вверх и галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<People> listPeople1 = countryList.stream()
    .flatMap(country -> country.getPeopleList().stream())
    .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 28)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```